Question about excision axiom
I have read about the excision axiom in Hatcher's book about topology where it is stated as follows:
Theorem 2.20. Given subspaces $Z \subseteq A \subseteq X$ such that the closure of $Z$ is contained
in the interior of $A$, then the inclusion $(X−Z,A−Z) ֓\hookrightarrow (X,A)$ induces isomorphisms $H_n(X−Z,A−Z) \to H_n(X,A)$ for all $n$.
My question now is: Why do we need $\bar{Z} \subseteq \mathring{A}$? Obviously we do need it otherwise it would not be stated but I cannot think of a counterexample where the lack of this condition is a problem. TIA!

Here's an easy counterexample: Take $X = S^n$ for some $n > 0$ and let $A = Z = S^n \setminus \{p\}$ for some choice of $p \in S^n$.
Obviously we have $\bar{Z} = S^n$ so the excision condition is not fulfilled, and a look at the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^n, S^n \setminus \{p\})$ reveals that $H_*(S^n, S^n \setminus \{p\}) \cong \tilde{H}_*(S^n)$ since $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ is contractible. But $(S^n \setminus (S^n \setminus \{p\}), (S^n \setminus \{p\}) \setminus (S^n \setminus \{p\})) = (\{p\}, \emptyset)$, and
$$
    \mathbb{Z} \cong \tilde{H}_n(S^n) \ncong H_n(\{p\}) = 0 
$$
